# Set minimum value to a specific column in R

Tags: r, rounding, minimum

I would like to set `0.0001` as the minimum value to a specific column in R. My input:

```
 df <- 'Tagx  value
 1 0 
 2 1
 2  1 
 3  0 '
df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)
```

My expected output:

```
dfout <- 'Tagx  value
 1 0.0001 
 2 1
 2  1 
 3  0.0001 '
dfout <- read.table(text=dfout, header=T)
```

Some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily vectorize this:

```
dfout$value[dfout$value <  0.0001] <-  0.0001
```

### Explanation

With this you replace all values lower than your threshold (here 0.0001) by the value of your threshold (0.0001)

How is that?

```
dfout$value[dfout$value <  0.0001]
```

Will select all positions in your vector `dfout$value` meeting your criterion  `dfout$value <  0.0001`.

You replace all these positions by 0.0001, and as R recycles the argument, you do not need to worry about the size of the vector you want to replace.

Answer (score 1):

The `pmin` and `pmax` functions can be used for setting upper and lower bounds respectively. arguments are recycled so a single value will become the bound. It can seem a bit odd that `pmax` needs to be used to set a minimum:

```
df$value <- pmax(0.0001, df$value)
df
#
  Tagx value
1    1 1e-04
2    2 1e+00
3    2 1e+00
4    3 1e-04
```